# Camera2 Pass Images from ImageReader to MediaRecorder

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera, surfaceview, android-camera2

I'm trying to create a Camera2 `CameraCaptureSession` that is capable of four outputs:

1. On-screen preview (`SurfaceView`, up to 1080p)
2. Photo capture (`ImageReader`, up to 8k photos)
3. Video Capture (`MediaRecorder`/`MediaCodec`, up to 4k videos)
4. Frame Processing (`ImageReader`, up to 4k video frames)

Unfortunately Camera2 does not support attaching all of those four outputs (Surfaces) at the same time, so I'm going to have to make a compromise.

The compromise that seemed most logical to me was to combine the two video capture pipelines into one, so that the Frame Processing output (#4, `ImageReader`) redirects the frames into the Video Capture output (#3, `MediaRecorder`).

How do I write the Images from the ImageReader:

```kotlin
val imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(4000, 2256, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 3)
imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
  val image = reader.acquireNextImage() ?: return@setOnImageAvailableListener
  callback.onVideoFrameCaptured(image)
}, queue.handler)

val captureSession = device.createCaptureSession(.., imageReader.surface)
```

..into the `Surface` from the `MediaRecorder`?

```kotlin
val surface = MediaCodec.createPersistentInputSurface()
val recorder = MediaRecorder(context)
..
recorder.setInputSurface(surface)
```

---

I'm thinking that I might need an OpenGL pipeline here with a pass-through shader - but I don't know how I get from the `ImageReader`'s `Image` to an OpenGL texture, so any help here would be appreciated.

---

What I tried: I looked into the HardwareBuffer APIs, specifically

```cpp
auto clientBuffer = eglGetNativeClientBufferANDROID(hardwareBuffer);
...
auto image = eglCreateImageKHR(display,
                               EGL_NO_CONTEXT,
                               EGL_NATIVE_BUFFER_ANDROID,
                               clientBuffer,
                               attribs);
...
glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES(GR_GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL, image);
```

And I think this might work, but it requires API Level 28. So I still need a solution for API Level 23 and above. The `image.getPlanes()` function returns me three `ByteBuffer`s for the YUV data, not sure how I can create an OpenGL texture from there though..

Comment: Did you try to use a `Surface` created from a `SurfaceTexture` with the `CameraCaptureSession`? This should make video frames available as an OpenGL external texture.

Comment: @dev.bmax I did, yes, but I need `Image` instances because I use other ML APIs that only take `Image`s as an argument.

Comment: In other words, I need to use an `ImageReader` to begin with, then go through an OpenGL pipeline to also draw to the Video Recording Surface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (kinda) figured it out! I found the [`ImageWriter` API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageWriter), which is exactly what I was about to rebuild from scratch - a pass-through pipeline from an Image to a Surface.

So now I stream Camera Frames into the `ImageReader`, call the Frame Processor with the `Image`, then pass the `Image` through to the `MediaRecorder` using the `ImageWriter` as a middle-man :)

```swift
val size = config.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.PRIVATE).max()

// Video Recorder Surface. We need to stream Frames here if we are recording.
val surface = recordingSession.surface
val imageWriter = ImageWriter.newInstance(surface,
                                          VIDEO_OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE)

// Image Reader Surface. We stream Frames here for Frame Processor or Recording.
val flags = HardwareBuffer.USAGE_GPU_SAMPLED_IMAGE or HardwareBuffer.USAGE_VIDEO_ENCODE
val imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(size.width,
                                          size.height,
                                          ImageFormat.PRIVATE,
                                          VIDEO_OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE,
                                          flags)

imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
  val image = reader.acquireNextImage() ?: return
  image.timestamp = System.nanoTime()

  // Call JS Frame Processor
  frameProcessor?.call(image)
                                         
  // If recording, write to Video File             
  if (isRecording) {
    imageWriter.queueInputImage(image)
  }

  image.close()
}, CameraQueues.videoQueue)

// Camera only streams frames into one single Surface
cameraSession.configure(.., imageReader.surface)
```

My only problem now is that the resulting video recording sometimes has ~1 second long hickups after around ~3 seconds of recording, I have no idea why. Maybe I should use `MediaCodec` instead of `MediaRecorder`. Maybe I should use a different `ImageFormat`. Maybe I should investigate the resulting `.mp4` file to see what's wrong. Maybe I should fix the Image timestamps. I don't know.

Also, logcat gets spammed with this:

```
2023-08-17 11:38:17.977  3780-3899  GraphicBufferSource     com.mrousavy.camera.example          W  released unpopulated slots: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]
2023-08-17 11:38:18.021  3780-3899  GraphicBufferSource     com.mrousavy.camera.example          W  released unpopulated slots: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]
2023-08-17 11:38:18.050  3780-3899  GraphicBufferSource     com.mrousavy.camera.example          W  released unpopulated slots: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]
2023-08-17 11:38:18.082  3780-3899  GraphicBufferSource     com.mrousavy.camera.example          W  released unpopulated slots: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]
2023-08-17 11:38:18.113  3780-3899  GraphicBufferSource     com.mrousavy.camera.example          W  released unpopulated slots: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]
2023-08-17 11:38:18.146  3780-3899  GraphicBufferSource     com.mrousavy.camera.example          W  released unpopulated slots: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]
2023-08-17 11:38:18.179  3780-3899  GraphicBufferSource     com.mrousavy.camera.example          W  released unpopulated slots: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]
```

But hey - it records a video. This is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have an `android.media.Image` that you need to make available to the OpenGL pipeline.

I would suggest the following setup:

1. Create an OpenGL texture using `glGenTextures()`.
2. Create a [SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture#SurfaceTexture(int)) using the texture name (which is actually an integer) from the previous step.
3. Create a [Surface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface#Surface(android.graphics.SurfaceTexture)) from the `SurfaceTexture`.
4. Create an [ImageWriter](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/ImageWriter?hl=en#newInstance(android.view.Surface,%20kotlin.Int)) passing the `Surface` from the previous step.
5. For each video frame call [queueInputImage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/ImageWriter?hl=en#queueInputImage(android.media.Image)), using the available `Image`.

** Don't forget to call [setOnFrameAvailableListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture#setOnFrameAvailableListener(android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener,%20android.os.Handler)) when you prepare the `SurfaceTexture` and then [updateTexImage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture#updateTexImage()) for every video frame.

*** If you want to handle image orientation correctly, you can use [getTransformMatrix()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture#getTransformMatrix(float%5B%5D)) and transform texture coordinates in the vertex shader.

Comment: Hey - thanks for your reply! I was able to skip the OpenGL part and just directly use `ImageWriter` to write Images to the `MediaRecorder` Surface (see my answer above).

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there are some hickups and I have no idea why, do you think the extra OpenGL route could solve this?

Comment: I am not familiar with the internals of `MediaRecorder` but I suspect that it ignores the presentation timestamps of the images. This could result in uneven playback. `MediaCodec` + `MediaMuxer` are probably better suited for this task.

Comment: Yep, will probably go with MediaCodec + MediaMuxer in a custom OpenGL pipeline soon as I need some more advanced stuff. Then I'll just need to figure out how to write the OpenGL Texture to an Image/ImageWriter

Comment: Hey @dev.bmax! I am using ImageWriter + MediaRecorder right now, and for some reason I cannot pass images through to MediaRecorder's surface. Do you maybe have any idea why? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77152531